# Static method call from JUnit test without specifying class

Tags: java, junit

Is it possible to call a static method from a junit test without specifying it's class?

The following code works:

```
package lightsOut;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import lightsOut.LightsOutModel;

public class LightsOutModelTest {

    @Test
    public void testLightsOutModel1(){
        assertTrue(LightsOutModel.checkWin()); // Note here
    }

}
```

But when I remove the class from the following line it shows an error.

```
        assertTrue(checkWin()); // Note here
```

The error is: 
*The method checkWin() is undefined for the type LightsOutModelTest*

Do I always have to specify the class on the static method call? Isn't there a way to import all the methods from the class because the way I tried to do it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Did you try it? Also your answer is in that link. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito]

Comment: `import static lightsOut.LightsOutModel.checkWin;`.  The interesting thing is that your code already does this.  That's why you don't need to specify the class to call `assertTrue`.

Comment: @ajb You mean the code is already doing this for the JUnit stuff :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a static import of the method:

```
import static lightsOut.LightsOutModel.checkWin;
```

Once you import, you can directly use them,

```
checkWin();
```

[Here is the official reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)